# .htaccess | no redirect if there is an specific parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, parameters, url-rewriting

im doing a cms at the moment
now im struggeling with the ajax implementation

i have everything running except a mod_rewrite problem..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.html index.php [L]
```

this redirects nothing except html files to index.php

i need a second rule witch checks the REQUEST_URI for a parameter to prevent the full site gets loaded by ajax.

i dont think this is understandable so i just post what i want to achieve^^

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?rewrite=no$)
RewriteRule \.html index.php [L]
```

i want nothing redirected except html files and also no redirect on url's with "(.html)?rewrite=no" at the end

hope someone can help me since rewrites and regexp are not my stongest stuff

thanks in advance

Comment: Your description is a little confusing - you say you are currently redirecting everything _except_ `.html` files into `.index.php`, but the rule you have in place now rewrites _only_ `.html` requests. Is that what you meant?

Comment: woops yeah gotta change that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> REQUEST_URI
>   The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". This notably excludes the query string which is available as as its own variable named QUERY_STRING.

So you are actually looking to match on `%{QUERY_STRING}` rather than `%{REQUEST_URI}`. Don't include the `?` on the query string when matching its condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Match the absence of rewrite=no in the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rewrite=no [NC]
# Then rewrite .html into index.php
RewriteRule \.html index.php [L]
```